# React native extending styles for landscape

Tags: react-native

Is this good approach of handling layout when device orientation changes to landscape or portrait?

```
const common = {
  container: {
    flex: 1
  }
}

// styles for portait orientation
const portrait = StyleSheets.create({
   container: {
     ...common.container,
     marginBotton: 10
   }
})

// styles for landscape
const landscape = StyleSheets.create({
   container: {
     ...common.container,
     flex: 0.5
   }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

for orientation issue you can use Dimensions, which takes the dimensions and according to your screen changes style.

```
import {  Dimensions } from 'react-native';
const { width, height } = Dimensions.get('window')

class SearchBox extends Component {
 render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
              //yous codes here
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
            width: width,
        }
});
```

Comment: Using dimension means flex-box is not properly used. I'm actually talking about splitting the styles.